# Is "Bingo voting" insecure against a corrupt election authority?

Tags: voting

I am reading about "Bingo voting"  ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingo_voting), [Paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/162.pdf)), and 
I'm not understanding how it is secure against a corrupt election authority.

If the election authority knows all the dummy votes $N_j^i$, can't it just look at any voter's ballot and tell who they voted for (by finding the candidate on the ballot whose vote is not a dummy vote)?

**My question**: does the election authority have to be trusted in order for people's votes to be secret from the authorities?

Comment: Well, can you define the capabilities of the corrupt election authority? Does it contain access to the random number generator, observing the voting machine which is not open during the voting?

Comment: No, it just knows all the dummy votes @kelalaka

Comment: Thanks for your question -- I figured it out. I missed that the interactions with the voting machine are anonymous, so there's no way to link ballots with identities.

Comment: helper, would you mind answering your own question with the answer you inferred?